# Переход по ссылкам без перезагрузки

Tags: javascript

Как переходить по ссылкам на сайте без её перезагрузке с помощью JavaScript?

Comment: Попробуйте Barba.js: [**документация**](http://barbajs.org/), [**примеры**](http://barbajs.org/demos.html). Спасибо.

Comment: Про `AJAX` никогда ничего не слышали?

Comment: @Air А как с помощью ajax реализуют это?

Comment: Судя по вопросу, тут одним комментом не обойтись...

Comment: Или же, я когда про `ajax` не знал я реализовал подобное, удаляя и создавая новые вкладки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это single page application (SPA), реализовано там это динамической подгрузкой html через Ajax и вставки этого html в страницу. Наивная реализация - это делать маршрутизацию по якорям и при смене этих якорей загружать определённый html фрагмент и вставлять в нужное место, более сложный вариант, писать клиентскую часть веб приложения на фреймворке типа angular, react, vue которые это умеют из коробки